# Gamelin Theorem 1.6

Tags: general-topology

In Gamelin and Greene, Theorem 1.6 is stated:

Let Y be a subspace of a metric space X. Then a subset U of Y is open in Y if and only if $U = V  \cap  Y$ for some open subset V of X.

The proof starts:

1. Because the metric d' : $Y \times Y \rightarrow R$ is the restriction to $Y \times Y$ of the metric d': $X \times X \rightarrow R$ on X, the open ball in the metric space $Y$ with center $y \in Y$ and radius $r > 0$ is just the intersection $B(y;r) \cap Y$ of $Y$ and the open ball $B(y;r)$ in $X$.
2. If $V$ is open in $X$, then for each $y \in V \cap Y$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(y;r) \subset V$.
3. Then the open ball in $Y$ centered at $y$ with radius $r$ is contained in $V \cap Y = U$.
4. Consequently each $y \in V \cap Y$ is an interior point of $V \cap Y$ in the subspace $Y$, so that $U = V \cap Y$ is open in Y.

---

I am confused by step 3. 
Does this theorem require that $V \subset Y$? 
Otherwise, I don't see that this step follows necessarily as part of the open ball B(y;r) might be outside of the intersection with Y. Perhaps someone can please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1):

It’s confusingly stated. What is meant in (3) is $B_{d'}(y;r)$, the open ball in the space $Y$, not $B_d(y;r)$, the open ball in the space $X$. The argument is that since $B_d(y;r)\subseteq V$ and $B_{d'}(y;r)=B_d(y;r)\cap Y\subseteq Y$, therefore $B_{d'}(y;r)\subseteq V\cap Y$.

Comment: I think I was (and still am a little) confused about what an open ball and an open subset means in a subset of a larger space.  Thanks, this makes more sense. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @topoquestion: You’re welcome. It might be easiest just to think of it in terms of the theorem from Gamelin & Greene, which is usually taken as the *definition* of the subspace topology: a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in the subspaces topology on $Y$ if and only if there is an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $U=V\cap Y$. Just intersect all of $X$’s open sets with $Y$, and you get $Y$’s open sets.